# Autocomplete does not find place with '!'

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using autocomplete and I notice that a place called Play! (in 170 State St. Los Altos CA) is not returned in the autocomplete results.
I can find the place in google places so I know it exists:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Play!+170+State+Street,+Los+Altos,+CA,+US&hl=en&sll=31.406252,35.081059&sspn=7.188377,16.907959&hq=Play!&hnear=170+State+St,+Los+Altos,+Santa+Clara,+California+94022&t=m&z=17

Following is the query I used to find it (removing the API key of course):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Play!&types=establishment&location=37.379935,-122.116057&radius=50&sensor=false&key=

Same query without the input param "Play!" fails to find it as well

Answer (score 0):

I just try to use your query with my key and i had the good result. I try too without the param "Play!" and it didn't work. But if you remove the '!' it work again.

So i think your problem is with your key. But anyway i recommend you to avoid special character in your input query.

Hope it help.

Comment: What do you mean you got good result? Did you have "Play!" appear in your results?

Comment: Exactly, i checked on google maps and it was the same result so for me it's a good result. As i said maybe it's a problem with your key.